# Clean way to get mousePressed event notified to QGraphicsView

Tags: qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I inherited from QGraphicsItemGroup and made a class that keeps a pointer to its contained items so that I can later refer to them and change properties. It has an ellipse item and a line item and I want only the ellipse to be clickable. I need that press event of the ellipse to propagate to the QGraphicsView so that I can send a signal to some surrounding widgets.

So far I tried inheriting also from QGraphicsObject to have signals available but got stuck with ambigous base error when trying to use scene->addItem. I tried casting to QGraphicsItemGroup but I still get the error. I also tried inheriting from QObject with no success.

I'm new to QGraphics and I know the QGraphics framework has a lot of tools for user interaction and even interaction between GraphicsItems but this is really kicking my butt.

What would be the proper way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

### Create a separate "emitter" class

To allow your subclass of QGraphicsItemGroup to emit signals, you can create a separate "emitter" class that inherits from QObject.  Then, you can add an instance of this emitter class within your subclass of QGraphicsItemGroup.  The emitter object can then emit signals for your subclass as needed.

### QGraphicsItemGroup is treated as a single item

Unfortunately, an instance of QGraphicsItemGroup is treated as a single item, so each mousePressEvent will belong to the entire group rather than one of the members of that group (i.e., the ellipse item or the line item).  If you want the mousePressEvent to behave differently depending on which item is clicked, they will need to be separate items, or you could try using `line->setParentItem(ellipse)` to link up the 2 items without using QGraphicsItemGroup.